# React lifecycle method caused cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

lifecycle method is causing multiple rerender and I fail to get pathname for the first time due to error of

```
cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
```

I have this code in my higher order component

```
@connect(state=>state.job,{})
export default function CheckPermission(EnhancedComponent) {
  return class Redirect extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
      //error is here
      this.on_applied_job_route = this.props.location.pathname.includes('applied_job')
    }

    render() {
      if (this.props.has_applied_job && !this.on_applied_route) {
        return <Redirect to={`/dashboard/ad/${this.props.has_applied_job}/applied_job`} />
      }

      return <EnhancedComponent { ...this.props } />
    }
  }
}
```

Strange thing is if I remove the logic in render method and do this
`console.log(this.props.location.pathname.includes('applied_job'))` it's fine. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Means `location` prop is not being passed. Unless you show how you use this HOC I'm gonna guess you just do not pass it. Try:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

@connect(state=>state.job,{})
export default function CheckPermission(EnhancedComponent) {
  class WithRedirect extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
      //error is here
      this.on_applied_job_route = this.props.location.pathname.includes('applied_job')
    }

    render() {
      if (this.props.has_applied_job && !this.on_applied_route) {
        return <Redirect to={`/dashboard/ad/${this.props.has_applied_job}/applied_job`} />
      }

      return <EnhancedComponent { ...this.props } />
    }
  }

  return withRouter(WithRedirect);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I haven't notice that before but you have component names duplicating - Redirect - which causes the infinite loop. I've corrected the code.

Comment: what did you changed? am I forgot the last line `return withRouter(Redirect);` ?

Comment: I used `withRouter` to inject `location` prop into Redirect component

Comment: but I got this warning `mapStateToProps() in Connect(Redirect) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.`

Comment: oh fixed that, thanks. But can I call api in this hoc? I got infinite loop trying to do that in componentDidMount, why?

Comment: I would need to see the example.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Rjepyqs6 this is it, the api call in componentDidMount caused infinite loop, I see the log non stop and freezed my entire app.

Comment: @JamieAden see the edit. You were trying to render itself over and over because there were names overlapping.

Comment: wow great spot, really thanks, but is this the right way to do HOC? I don't see ppl use lifecycle method much in HOC, they merely do the conditional logic straight in the render method. But for my case I have to because I have to call an api.

Comment: React-reduc connect uses lifecycle method shoulComponentUpdate. So it depends on situation